# Помогите найти библиотеку для создания простого софтфона(Python)

Tags: python, asterisk, sip, pjsip

Хочу автоматизировать процесс тестирования Asterisk-сервера.

Идея:

Написать простой sip-клиент для совершения вызовов на телефоны, подключенные к станции. Если при совершении вызова телефон на другом конце звонит - вывод об успешном выполнении теста. Asterisk и клиент будут на разных машинах.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать: библиотеку какую-нибудь найти или через api уже готового софтфона?

Answer (score 1):

Есть замечательная консольная утилита sipp, с ее помощью сможете тестировать как угодно.
Пример:

```
sipp <asterisk-host> -s <dest-extension> -i <local-interface-ip> -d 100s -l 200 -aa -mi <interface-ip> -rtp_echo -nd -r 10
```